# Selenium 2 WebDriver UnhandledAlertException Java

Tags: java, internet-explorer, netbeans, selenium-webdriver, maven-plugin

Now before I start getting scolded, I DID read through most of the existing questions about this and applied different solutions (which mostly repeat the same thing), but it still does not work for me.
I have a maven project with all necessary dependencies, and the website in testing is done specifically for IE and requires me to have a specific certificate in order to access it. I have the certificate for it, and when I go onto the website, before it loads the page it asks me to confirm that I have the certificate and I need to confirm on the pop-up window, THEN the login page fully loads.
[image: The image shows the page before I accept the certificate]

[image: The page loaded after I accept the certificate manually]

[image: NetBeans Persisting Error message]

I have done to typical:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3);
try {
    // Handle alert box
    driver.navigate().to("https://ke.m-pesa.com/ke/");
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    alert.accept();
} 
catch(Exception e) {
    //whatever
}
```

Can you tell me where I am going wrong? So far I have used only Selenium RC up till now so this webdriver stuff is still kind of new to me. Please tell me if you need any more info I need to provide.
Why do I still get the UnhandledAlertException?? and why can't I access the login page until I manually press the OK button?

Comment: I simply don't think the certificate window is an alert window.

Comment: What would you classify it as instead?

Comment: By saying, "It's not an alert window," what is really meant is that, "WebDriver can't recognize it as a window it can manipulate." The `Alert` interface is designed to handle **only** the dialogs generated by the JavaScript `alert()`, `confirm()`, and `prompt()` functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try using Robot? Something like :

```
     Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
     Robot a = new Robot();
     a.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

---

**Why robot and not Actions**

[From this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005007/selenium-actions-or-java-awt-robot) :

> There is a huge difference in terms of how do these tools work.
>   Selenium uses the WebDriver API and sends commands to a browser to
>   perform actions (through the "JSON wire protocol").
>
> Java AWT Robot uses native system events to control the mouse and
>   keyboard.
>
> If you are doing browser automation, ideally, you don't ever use
>   things like Robot since usually the functionality provided by selenium
>   is more than enough. Though, there are cases when there is a browser
>   or native OS popup opened, for example, to upload/download a file -
>   this is something that can be also solved with Robot -

Comment: Nice, weren't familiar with that. How is that different from the Actions class?

Comment: @StasS Didn't see you asked the question :). I leave that here for information. Thanks for asking.