# Keypress event not working for chrome browser in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to press the Enter/Cancel button on a security certificate which is shown while the application is loaded. It is a single-Sign-On (SSO Enabled).

Have a look at this **[Similar Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986032/selenium-2-webdriver-unhandledalertexception-java)**.

The below code works fine in IE and Firefox, but not in google chrome.

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
Robot a = new Robot();
a.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
a.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CANCEL);
```

I am using java with selenium webdriver.

Chrome version : 37.0.2062.120

Comment: Have you tried seeing AutoIT, since Robot is not working for chrome?

Answer (score 0):

This is my c# implementation that works for me, give it a try and see if it works for you.

```
IAlert alertDialog = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
alertDialog.Accept();
```

EDIT: adding java implementation

```
Alert alertDialog = driver.switchTo().alert();
alertDialog.accept();
```

Comment: Hi,
It is not working.
Actually it is not an alert. It is SSO enabled popup.
Kindly see the detailed description in below link.
'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986032/selenium-2-webdriver-unhandledalertexception-java'